# Converting Matrix in Swift to Java

Tags: java, swift, matrix

I'm trying to convert the below `Swift` code into Java, and I'm a little confused as to how the Arrays within Arrays work. For adding values within the array in Java I'm attempting:

```
if(level == 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < value; i++){
      mRep[level][i] = value;
    } else{
      for(int n : children){
        travers(n);
        mRep[]
      }
    }
```

and the code swift is implemented like below. I'm specifically trying to do what's going on in `if(level == 0)` statement.

```
// head of the tree
  var head : Node
  var matrixRepresentation : [[Int]] = [[]]
  var nodeCount : Int = 0

  // constructor
  init(head: Node) {
    self.head = head
    self.head.expand()
    for x in 0...(head.matches-2) {
      matrixRepresentation.append([])
    }
    traverse(self.head)
  }

  // traverse tree to store data in a matrix
  // so that it can be displayed in a top down approach
  func traverse(node: Node) {
    var level = node.level
    var value = node.value
    var children = node.children

    if level == 0 {
      matrixRepresentation[level].append(value)
      nodeCount++
    }
    for n in children {
      traverse(n)
      matrixRepresentation[level+1].append(n.value)
      nodeCount++
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `matrixRepresentation` be a 2D array of `int`...`int[][]`?

Comment: my equivalent of that is `mRep`. Just not sure of the structure they're using to pass in values in Swift